Why are object attributes empty while binding a model on EditForm in Blazor .net 8?
I'm working on a Blazor web app in new hosting mode of Blazor on .NET 8, where I tried to bind a product model to an EditForm, initialized model in OnInitializedAsync() method, but when the form is submitted, the attributes in the bound model (productModel) are always empty, despite the input fields being filled out in the UI. I expected the form data to bind correctly to the model.
I did also try to use breakpoints to monitors all values at runtime.
What could be causing the model not to bind properly to the form inputs?
Here is my code:
@page "/insertProduct"
@using DbContext DB
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

<h3>Insert New Product</h3>

<EditForm Model="@productModel" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Product Name</label>
        <InputText id="name" class="form-control" @bind-Value="productModel.Name" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="description">Description</label>
        <InputTextArea id="description" class="form-control" @bind-Value="productModel.Description" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="price">Price</label>
        <InputNumber id="price" class="form-control" @bind-Value="productModel.Price" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="stock">Stock</label>
        <InputNumber id="stock" class="form-control" @bind-Value="productModel.Stock" />
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</EditForm>

@if (isSubmitted)
{
    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
         submitted!
    </div>
}

@code {
    [SupplyParameterFromForm]
    private Product productModel {get;set;}
    private bool isSubmitted = false;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        productModel = new Product();
    }

    private async Task HandleValidSubmit()
    {
        isSubmitted = true;
        DB.Products(productModel); // product is empty here
        await DB.SaveChangesAsync();
        productModel = new Product(); 
    }
}


I think DB is null. Please check or post the real code.

I do use DB with same way but without ediform, works well. the issue is product model is empty while submission.

Because productModel is recreated empty instance on every initialized. It should be
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        if (productModel == null)
        {
            productModel = new Product();
        }
    }

Or generally shortly used
protected override void OnInitialized() => productModel ??= new Product();


I really appreciate for your reply, but the issue is still same. model is empty while submit form.

@AwAzeem Sorry, it should be use == instead of !=. Do you use SSR rendermode? And I found you lack of "formname" attribute for the editform.  But in SSR, you have to add this attribute.

I think OnInitializedAsync is calling once again on submit form. I think its  its making it null. that's what I observer.

@AwAzeem If using SSR, the OnInitializedAsync will be trigger again when you click submit. So we need to confirm the rendermode. But as my answer suggeated, even it is triggered again, the productModel shouldn't be newly created.

Okay I understand, I its just Static Server by default if not hosting model is specified, basically  its created using  .Net 8 WebApp template. Thank you for that information.

Its working, when I initialize on object creation not in the OnInitializeAsync(),
private Product productModel {get;set;} = new Product();
and remove this line from oninitializedasync()
productModel = new Product();
